# AWS EKS Cross Cluster Load balancing between pods using Layer 4 ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

I have a situation where i'm deploying a k8s service of type LoadBalancer in one EKS cluster which is creating a Layer 4 ELB in AWS. This ELB can discover k8s pods in the same EKS cluster (based on label-selector) . What do I need to do so that same ELB (layer 4) can discover pods running in another EKS cluster ?

My primary use case is based around supporting cross cluster injection using mutating admission controller.

I have a mutating admission controller that injects a side car container in a pod. A webhook server (pod) is responsible for the actual injection (which I want to load balance across EKS clusters). I am trying to see if I can avoid deploying the webhook server in every EKS cluster which will help me in 2 ways :

1) Reduced monitoring / operational aspect

2) Since kube-api server is responsible for calling the webhook-server in an EKS cluster, if for whatever reason the webhook-server in that EKS cluster is unavailable , injection should still happen since we would have a webhook server running in another EKS cluster.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you have many k8s clusters (more than 2), and you want to deploy a server, not to all the clusters, but to (at least) 2 of the clusters for some redundancy. Is that right?

Comment: Load Balancers don’t discover pods, they blindly balance traffic to all nodes on the given nodeport, it’s kubeproxy’s job to them route traffic on the container network to the selected pods (possibly running on another node).

Comment: If you want to have a LB send traffic to nodes in multiple k8s clusters, you’ll have to create that LB yourself manually, and configure it to target nodes in both k8s clusters. You would need to expose your server as a nodeport service with the same nodeport for both clusters. Alternatively you could solve this upstream with DNS, and have a separate LB service for each cluster your server is running on, and cut over DNS from one to the other in event of a disaster.